# Why this happen with || operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I read carefully in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) about || , it said:

> o3 = true  || false   ==> return true

[image]

But when i try something like:

```
const x = 3
console.log(x === (4||3))
```

Why it return false?

Comment: 4 || 3 = 4 from the same doc you linked...

Comment: `==` doesn't distribute over `||`. So `x === (4||3)` is not the same as `x === 4 || x === 3`. First it calculates the result of `4 || 3`, which is `4`. Then it does `x === 4`, which is false.

Comment: `4||3` will take the first truthy value,  `4`. 4 != 3.

Comment: Now i got it, it run the || first

Comment: See [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: You could replace your statement by `[3,4].includes(x)` to make it work in the way you intended.